# How to search for exact word/phrase in multiple PDF/Epub documents at once?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, android, search, epub

I have several folders divided by genre and each folder contains many books which are in PDF and Epub formats. Right now if I want to find specific word/phrase I have to do this in a traditional way, by opening separately each book and unfortunately it takes time. Therefore I'm curious if there is a way to search for a specific word/phrase through all these books at once. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got Content search set up in Windows 10 Indexing setup for these two file extension types?   Windows search (if properly setup up) will find your phrase in all documents with the phrase.

Comment: No, I have not. And I must admit that I'm a little suprised because I haven't heard about "Indexing setup" until now. Could you explain to me what should I do to make your method work?

Comment: I will post a picture later today.  Control Panel, indexing options.  Advanced. File types and look at the extensions.  Document types (like PDF) allow Content Search.  First tab allows locations and where Search will look.

Comment: EPUB files may be ZIP files so you may wish to allow content search in ZiP files.

Comment: Adobe Reader supports as far as I remember searching for text in all pdf files within a folder or folder structure.

Comment: If Windows *Search* cannot search into EPUB files, after you rebuild the index, you might try a third-party tool such as DocFetcher, which can look inside a great many file types: http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find multiple documents quickly, you need to set up Indexing.

Control Panel, Indexing Options.

**(A)** First make sure Locations include where your documents are.

[image: Locations]

**(B)** Second, set up File Types for contents. I showed PDF and you can see Contents has been selected.

[image: Contents]

At this point, if you change things (you likely will) you need to click on the Advanced button and rebuild your index (takes some time)

**(C)** Finally, when you search using Windows, make sure you restrict your search to Documents (not All).

[image: Restrict to Documents]

**(D)** You can also use File Explorer to narrow your locations and use the Upper Right search bar in Explorer to Search.

Good luck with this